# Why doesn't the Second Sister deactivate her lightsaber when she gets it stuck in the ground?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

In Jedi Fallen Order, the Second Sister has an unblockable move where she stabs her lightsaber into the ground. While doing this, Cal is able to get a few licks in while she struggles to pull it out.

I don't understand this. Why can't she just deactivate the lightsaber, pull it out, and continue fighting, instead of leaving herself open?

Comment: Um, you realize this is a *game*, right? If the devs didn't do things like that, you wouldn't have as many openings to hit the boss to move forward in the game.

Comment: This would be during the fight sequence where you can repeatedly get hit by a lightsaber on your bare head and suffer no ill consequences?

Comment: This was the only instance where I could remember someone struggling to pull out there lightsaber.

Answer (score 10):

I've found some [footage of that fight sequence](https://youtu.be/wyza1l7pxwY?t=121). It seems that *without distraction* she can pull it out in approximately 1 second, then stand ready to fight again. This is less than the amount of time that it would take to deactivate the blade, then reactivate it again.

[image]

If she's distracted by being hit at the same time, then it takes longer for her to pull the lightsaber free, but that's **merely a quirk of the game mechanics wherein someone can't act while they're being hit** and the odd way that makers have chosen to represent a lightsaber fight, not as a samurai fight where the participants are seeking a single killing stroke, but a kendo fight where points are scored by repeated contact.